# Compare two columns in a table in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to compare columns in a dynamic table that can vary in length and highlight the ones that do not match?

I need to check if the values in columns B match somewhere in column A, and if not, highlight that cell, but if the cell is empty I don't want to highlight it.
I also need a variable that becomes True if all values in column B (except empty cells) has a match in column A to trigger a refresh that looks like below:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

Columns
[image: Columns]

EDIT:

I tried this, but it does the opposite of what I want. The code highlights the cells in B that exists in A. I've tried to invert the function.

```vb
Sub CompareAndHighlight()

    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To Sheets("Mätplan").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng1 = Sheets("Mätplan").Range("A" & i)
        For j = 1 To Sheets("Mätplan").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Set rng2 = Sheets("Mätplan").Range("B" & j)
            If (StrComp(Trim(rng1.Text), Trim(rng2.Text), vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
                rng2.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                'rng2.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            Else
                'rng2.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                'rng2.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            End If
            Set rng2 = Nothing
        Next j
        Set rng1 = Nothing
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Just use conditional formatting.

Comment: Some examples on how? @BigBen

Comment: Thank you, but I've already looked there and on other sites but thats not really what I'm looking for. Or maybe I'm just missing something, sorry. @BigBen

Comment: The highlighting is easily accomplished by conditional formatting. The second part of your question has nothing to do with highlighting, and is easily overlooked. You might consider narrowing your question down. I'd use a `Variant` array and loop for the second part.

Comment: I find the highlighting easy if I want to highlight the unique values ​​in both columns but not if I only want to highlight the values ​​in column B that does not exist in column A. In this case B6. Any sugestions? @BigBen

Answer (score 0):

Using conditional formatting to highlight matches:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(LEN(B2)>0,(MATCH(B2, A$2:A$1000, 0)>0)),TRUE),FALSE)
```

Using conditional formatting to highlight failed matches:

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEN(B2)>0,IF(MATCH(B2,$A$2:$A$1000,0)>0,FALSE),FALSE),TRUE)
```

Apply to range: `=$B$2:$B$1000` and assign the Format you want the cell to show when the value is `TRUE`

> Take note of the use of the dollar sign to designate whether the value is absolute or not.

If there are issues with whitespace, you may want to add in a TRIM function as well.

For the second part, a function such as the following should work:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(B2:B1000,A2:A1000))+COUNTBLANK(B2:B1000)=ROWS(A2:A1000),TRUE,FALSE)
```